# Find integer in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have got:

```
var myclass = 'moreElements showAddElements-570';
var re = new RegExp('showAddElements\-\d*');
var m = re.exec(myclass);

alert(m[0]);
alert(m[1]);
```

First alert results in *'showAddElements-'*, second alert in *'undefined'*. I would like to get '570', what I am doing wrong here? If I [test](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) it, I get there at least *'showAddElements-570'* ... what am I doing wrong here?

Thx for any tipps!

P.s.: I'd like the number only after 'showAddElements-', all other numbers should be omitted..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the correct regex:

```
var re = /showAddElements-(\d+)/;
```

I removed the backslash before the dash (not needed) and added parens around the digits to turn it into a capturing group -- otherwise `m[1]` would always be `undefined`.

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shea4/).

Comment: Thx, works like a charm! ... D'Oh, I didn't realize there shouldn't be any single (or double) quotes!

Comment: @sl3dg3: In JavaScript you can construct regexes either with `new Regex("blah")` or with the bare `/blah/`. Different syntax, same result.

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually capture the subpattern you want:

```
/showAddElements-(\d*)/
```

Note that you don't need to escape `-` because it has no meaning outside a character class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that works:

```
var myclass = 'moreElements showAddElements-570';
var re = new RegExp(/showAddElements\-(\d*)/);
var m = re.exec(myclass);
alert(m[1]);
```

There were two problems with the `RegExp` line. First problem is that the expression was wrapped with single quotes instead of slashes. This blew my mind the first time I realized what was up, had no clue you could wrap something with slashes. Without these it was just treated as a string intend of an expression.

The second problem is that the there were no `()` around the number part. You need that to actually "grab" that part.

Here's a working link: http://jsfiddle.net/MvG2C/

Answer (score 0):

You have to add parentheses around the desired class in order to capture it:

```
var re = new RegExp('showAddElements\-([0-9]*)');
```